# Verify a startActivity and callBackListener from inside a method using Mocktio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a following method in class named
`CommunicationManager`

```
public void makeCall(Context context, String number, CallListener communicationCallListener) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(SCHEME_TYPE_TEL + number));
            context.startActivity(intent);

            if (communicationCallListener != null) {
                communicationCallListener.phoneClickCallBackListener();
            }
        }
    }
```

Through examples what I have learned is that I can use `mock` against the source which is calling an inside method, for my case it's an `activityStart` call and a `callBack` listener which is trigger at the same place.

So far what I could do is shown below, but I am a little confused about few things

```
    @Test
    public void test_makeCall() {
        String dummyNumber = "+xxx-xxx-xxxx";

        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + dummyNumber));

        communicationManager.makeCall(mockContext, dummyNumber, callListener);
        verify(communicationManager).makeCall(mockContext, dummyNumber, callListener);

        mockContext.startActivity(intent);
        verify(mockContext, times(1)).startActivity(intent);

        callListener.phoneClickCallBackListener();
        verify(callListener, times(1)).phoneClickCallBackListener();
    }
```

1 - In my test method `startActivity` method is called but I have no reference if it's from that method I am trying to test.
2 - Same is for `callBack` listener
3 - Should I mock the class I am writing test cases against? in my case `CommunicationManager`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to mock the `CommunicationManager` class as long as the constructor for the `Intent` class can be called safely.  But you do need to mock the `Context` and `CallListener` classes passed in as arguments. You will need to mock the `PackageManager` and mock the response to `packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)` as true or false.  If this method does not return true, the test will never access the block in the if statement.  You will also have to inject the 'PackageManager' mock as the return value from `context.getPackageManager()`.

In the test, in the following lines, you call methods and then verify that you called then. So the answer to your first and second questions is no, they are not being called from inside the method under test. This doesn't add much value.

```
mockContext.startActivity(intent);
verify(mockContext, times(1)).startActivity(intent);

callListener.phoneClickCallBackListener();
verify(callListener, times(1)).phoneClickCallBackListener();
```

If you delete the lines `callListener.phoneClickCallBackListener();` and `mockContext.startActivity(intent);` from that section of the test, the test should fail until you mock the `packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)` to return true and the methods are called in the if statement block.